# GetValue() does not read decimal values when first row is string

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, c#-3.0, oledb

'm using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider for reading data from Excel Sheet.
I'm using `OleDbDataReader` and his `GetValue()` for getting data. 
First row/rows (can be more then one) is string header and I can't to skip it.
Next are the numeric data that are set to 0 decimal place, but when I choose one of them, it appears in the bar in the correct decimal format.

How can I read this mixed data in full original decimal format like the bar in Excel?
I can't change settings of excel sheet.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
using System.Data.OleDb;

    namespace ConsoleApplication2
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string query = "SELECT * FROM [List1$]";
                string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\Temp\Test.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1""";
                using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection))
                    {
                        using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                object value = reader.GetValue(0);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried ".GetDecimal" instead of ".GetValue" ?

Comment: Yes. GetDecimal throw an exception, because there is the space characters. GetFieldType returned string. So it must be somewhere in OleDbCommand or OleDbConnection settings, maybe some attribut in connection string.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

Try using `HDR=YES` in your connection string and stop skipping the first row:

```
string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\Temp\Test.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1""";
```

**[UPDATE]**

A workaround that I would suggest would you to use is reading twice the file (with the same method):

1. First, you get the header row, probably you will need that for the data structure later
2. On a second read, you skip the header and read the rows.

Here's how it should look like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // the Excel file
        string file = @"c:\Temp\Test.xls";

        if (!File.Exists(file))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File not found.");
            return;
        }

        // DataTable bonus! :)
        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();

        IEnumerable<List<object>> header = new List<List<object>>();
        IEnumerable<List<object>> rows = new List<List<object>>();

        // read the header first
        header = GetData(file, true);

        // read the rows
        rows = GetData(file, false);

        // add the columns
        foreach (var column in header.First())
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(column.ToString());
        }

        // add the rows
        foreach (var row in rows)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(row.ToArray());
        }

        // now you may use the dt DataTable for your purpose
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Read from the Excel file
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="file">The path to the Excel file</param>
    /// <param name="readHeader">True if you want to read the header, 
    /// False if you want to read the rows</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static IEnumerable<List<object>> GetData(string file, bool readHeader)
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM [List1$]";
        string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
            @"Data Source=" + file + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;IMEX="
            + ((readHeader) ? "1" : "0") + @";""";
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection))
            {
                using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    bool isHeaderRead = false;
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        if (readHeader && isHeaderRead)
                        { break; }
                        isHeaderRead = true;
                        List<object> values = new List<object>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                        {
                            values.Add(reader.GetValue(i));
                        }
                        yield return values;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works for these example, unfortunately I can't disable header by using HDR=YES.

Comment: thank you your solution looks like good workaround but implement it wouldn't be easy for me.

Answer (score 2):

From experience, the best you're probably gonna do is the below.
I've always had issues with excel files, reading the data.
Which is why I despise excel as a data transport mechanism.

I worked for a company that got all its "bank data" through excel.
I'd be glad to be proven wrong.

Note.  After the GetValue(0) runs, put a watch on it.  It'll probably tell you its a string.
But you can determine what it thinks it is, then adjust your "Get" mehthod a tad.
Like, if the value is a "string", you can change GetValue(0) to GetString(0).

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    Decimal tryParseResultDec;
    object value = reader.GetValue(0);
    if !(Decimal.TryParse(value, out tryParseResultDec))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Unable to parse '{0}'.", value));   
    }

}
```

Extra Suggestion.

Instead of "0", "1", "2", etc, I usually put some private const's at the top of the class to tell me what the columns are.

```
private const int EXCEL_COLUMN_TOTAL_AMOUNT = 0;
```

(you may do something like that, and you just kept the example simple)

EXTRA HINT:

I think the way it works is that excel will look at the **first row of data** , and look at the datatype, and use that for the rest of the rows in that same column.  I do not think it says "check the datatype for each row".  And thus your conundrum.

If you say there is not a header row, it will look at A1 for the datatype for all rows in A.  If you say there is a header row, it will look at A2 for the datatype for all rows in A.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works if GetValue () return the correct data, but it returns the data without decimal places. Information about decimal is lost.

Comment: Ok, I see now.  The column has a hodge podge of data types.  Yeah.  The "formatting" setting will screw you.  We had to talk to our customers about this.  First, we had a rule that every column had to be consistent in data type.  They had data for "one record" in 2 rows.  Like, in row1, colA, there would be "LastName" and in row2 colA, there would be "TransactionAmount"...(row1 and row2 made one "record")  So we had to get them to either (1) make all the data on one excel row or (2) row1 colA had LastName and row2 colB had TAmount, but there was no data in row1 colB or row2 colA.

Comment: So the formatting was rounding off the individual amounts, and the aggregate data would be off by 1 penny sometimes.  We had to code in a rule to say "allow for 1 penny"...because of how excel was doing its rounding.     thus.........why i hated excel as a data transport mechanism.

Comment: I expected to GetValue() returns the original value, but it returns a value that is displayed in the excel table.

Comment: Read my "Extra Hint" in my answer.  That premise should be easy to test I think.

Comment: Alex's solution with reading excel in two steps and switching IMEX=0 and IMEX=1 seems to be little easier so thank you. I will try to argue into our customer to correct his data.